# Sum multiple columns grouped by month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ok let me show my table first.

My columns:

```
Outlet | tanggal | cash | cc | dc | flash | piutang | reject | disc50
```

What I have done is sum `per day`. My query so far

```
select 
    Outlet, tanggal,
    (cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50) total
from 
    transaksi 
where 
    outlet = 'K-AEON'
```

This query returns this result:

```
Outlet  tanggal      total
---------------------------
K-AEON  2016-01-22  2343300
K-AEON  2016-01-23  6091200
K-AEON  2016-01-24  6244700
K-AEON  2016-01-26  3284100
K-AEON  2016-01-25  1904600
K-AEON  2016-01-27  2743500
```

What I want is the result from above is `group by` with `month(tanggal)`.

So far I've tried this

```
select 
    Outlet, month(tanggal),
    (cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50) total 
from  
    transaksi 
where 
    outlet = 'K-AEON' 
group by 
    month(tanggal), Outlet, cash, cc, dc, flash, piutang, reject, disc50
```

and the result

```
Outlet  month   total
----------------------
K-AEON    1    811100
K-AEON    1    1220850
K-AEON    1    1169700
K-AEON    1    1147500
K-AEON    1    1290000
```

My desired result is

```
Outlet  month   total
----------------------------------------
K-AEON    1    10000000   // all of January
K-AEON    2    20000000   // All feb
K-AEON    3    30000000   // All march
K-AEON    4    40000000   // All April
K-AEON    5    50000000   // All may
```

Any help ? Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but you need to use `sum` and then exclude those fields from the `group by`:

```
select Outlet, month(tanggal),
       sum(cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50) total 
from transaksi 
where outlet = 'K-AEON' 
group by Outlet, month(tanggal)
```